# URL Regex for Apache Mod Rewrite

Tags: regex, apache

I have been trying to work the regex out for this for a while now and I am struggling. Was hoping someone could help.

I have a website using apache mod_rewrite converting directories into get variables to 1 level. I am wanting to change this or add a seperate rule for the following

example.com/portfolio/plugins/jquery-tester

becoming 
example.com/portfolio/handler.php?area=plugins&item=jquery-tester

I am trying to currently build up on php live regex but coming up trumps.

Comment: Did any of the posted answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/portfolio/(.+)/(.+)$ /portfolio/handler.php?area=$1&item=$2 [L]
```

Having the handler in the same directory as what you're matching can cause potential problems though (that's why the RewriteCond is there to check so you don't end up with an infinite loop).

If you have other rewrite rules, you may need to check that there aren't any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/portfolio/[a-zA-Z\-_]+/[a-zA-Z\-_]+$ /portfolio/handler.php?area=$1&item=$2 [L]
```